# Calculate length and width of polygons using Arcade in Expression Builder in the attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, extents, length, arcade

I am using attribute rules to automatically update cells in an attribute table. I need to auto-calculate the length and width of polygons as the user creates them.

Is there a way to do this using math/geometry functions in Arcade?

It would work similarly to the tool Minimum Bounding Geometry that can calculate the length and width of polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute rules run on [Immediate evaluation during editing](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/evaluate-attribute-rules.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_C30D73392D964D51A8B606128A8A6E8F) only use the scripting language [Arcade](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/author-attribute-rule-script-expressions.htm#GUID-A7CA5D69-CC3C-42F1-9E14-B92F38718EBA) and if you look at the list of [Geometry Functions](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/geometry_functions/) available there is no equivalence for Minimum Bounding Geometry that calculate the length and width of polygons. So the answer is no.

You could create a simple model/python script and get them to run it after they have finished editing so it updates/creates your required fields?